# MySQL select EVEN number and exclude zero

Tags: mysql

How to exclude IDs that ends with zero(0) when I am selecting the IDs with EVEN numbers

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE right(id,1) % 2 = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this condition with `and`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE right(id,1) % 2 = 0 and right(id,1)<>0 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT LIKE` operator

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE right(id,1) % 2 = 0
AND id NOT LIKE '%0';
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me try with REGEX

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE right(id,1) % 2 = 0 AND id NOT REGEXP '0$'
```

Answer (score 1):

If `id` is a number, treat it like a number; there is no number where `right(id,1) % 2 != id % 2`

```
where id % 2 = 0 and id % 10 != 0
```